# Proccessing tool to add a new field to existing vector attribute table

Tags: qgis-3

Isnt there a tool to add a new field to a existing vector table without creating a new dataset, like [Add Field](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-field.htm) in ArcGIS? All i can find is "Add field to attributes table" which creates a new vector dataset:

> Add field to attributes table This algorithm adds a new attribute to a
>   vector layer. The name and characteristics of the attribute are
>   defined as parameters. **The new attribute is not added to the input
>   layer but a new layer is generated instead.**

I know it is possible in the attribute table by editing - New field, but I want to create a model which starts with an empty Point layer and adds 15 fields to it.

[image]

Comment: Well, since you're working with a model, you could use that tool anyway and only save the final output?

Comment: Yes that is a possibility. Do you know of a tool to create a vector layer? Like the Icon "New Geopackage Layer" to start the model with? (Like "Create Feature Class" in ArcGIS)

Comment: `extent to layer` creates a polygon, `create grid` would give you points - but you need an empty layer, I guess? How about creating manually a template with all needed columns and then copying it each time you need it?

Comment: I can `Create grid` then `Truncate table`, thanks

Comment: @Erik you can add that as an answer if you want

Comment: Yeah, but you came up with `truncate` which you need to make my hint work for your case ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned/solved in the comments by @Erik, since Im using Proccessing Modeler I can use `Add field to attributes table` and only save final output.

To create a empty Point layer to start with I use `Random Points in extent` then `Truncate table`:

[image]